# How do I antialias the clip boundary on Android's canvas?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using Android's [android.graphics.Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class [to draw a ring](http://code.google.com/p/publicobject/source/browse/shush/src/com/publicobject/shush/ClockSlider.java). My onDraw method clips the canvas to make a hole for the inner circle, and then draws the full outer circle over the hole:

```
    clip = new Path();
    clip.addRect(outerCircle, Path.Direction.CW);
    clip.addOval(innerCircle, Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(clip);
    canvas.drawOval(outerCircle, lightGrey);
    canvas.restore();
```

The result is a ring with a pretty, anti-aliased outer edge and a jagged, ugly inner edge:

[image: aliased]

What can I do to antialias the inner edge?

I don't want to cheat by drawing a grey circle in the middle because the dialog is slightly transparent. (This transparency isn't as subtle on on other backgrounds.)

Comment: After so many years, I found that `clipPath` method supports antialiasing by default on my Android 12 (API 31) phone. But on Android 4.4(API 19) phone the clipped area still has a bad-looking edge. The documentation of Canvas did not mention about this change, so I do not know on what API level did this change happen.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't antialias clip regions.

I'd suggest using bitmap masking instead. Render the the pink, white, and light gray foreground to one bitmap, render the outer/inner circle mask (the grayscale alpha channel) to another bitmap, and then use `Paint.setXfermode` to render the foreground bitmap with the mask as its alpha channel.

An example can be found in the `ApiDemos` source code [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.html).

Comment: Either of the `DstOut`, `DstIn`, `SrcOut`, `SrcIn` would do the trick -- it just depends on how you structure the code.

Comment: Note that Xfermode doesn't works correctly on some devices when hardware acceleration is turned on. Consider using `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` for view.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is not a general answer, but in this particular case, you could draw arcs with a thick stroke width, instead of the circles + mask.

Answer (score 3):

I too had this same problem. I tried using Bitmap masking (xFermode) to fix the Aliasing, but it was heavy.

So for API < 19, I used the Bitmap masking way and for API >= 19, I used `Path.Op`. Instead of clipping the path and then drawing the shape. I did a `REVERSE_DIFFERENCE` of the `path` and the `shape`(which is of type Path). You can perform operations on Path from API 19 and above.

Works perfectly for me!

Comment: @iscariot it's straightforward. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#op(android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Path.Op)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, same solution. Three ways to draw round corner, 1.Clippath ( cannot fix anti-alias)2. xFermode (much more code )3. Drawpath(little math)

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code:

```
public class GrowthView extends View {
private static final String TAG = "GrowthView";
private int bgColor = Color.parseColor("#33485d");
private int valColor = Color.parseColor("#ecb732");
private int[] scores = new int[]{0, 10, 80, 180, 800, 5000, 20000, 50000, 100000};

private Context mContext;

private float w;
private float h;

private Paint bgPaint;
private Paint growthPaint;
private Paint textPaint;
private Paint clipPaint;
private Path bgPath;
private Path bgClipPath;
private Path growthPath;

private int growthValue = 0;

private float bgFullAngle = 240.0f;
private float gapAngle = bgFullAngle / (scores.length - 1);

private float gapRadius = 21.5f;//实际为21px 略大半个像素避免path无法缝合error
private float outerRadius = 240.0f;
private float innerRadius = outerRadius - gapRadius * 2;

private RectF outerRecF;
private RectF innerRecF;
private RectF leftBoundRecF;
private RectF rightBoundRecF;

public GrowthView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public GrowthView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public GrowthView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.mContext = context;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Xfermode xFermode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);

    bgPaint = new Paint();
    bgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    bgPaint.setColor(bgColor);
    bgPaint.setStrokeWidth(0.1f);
    bgPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    growthPaint = new Paint();
    growthPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    growthPaint.setColor(valColor);
    growthPaint.setStrokeWidth(1f);
    growthPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    clipPaint = new Paint();
    clipPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    clipPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    clipPaint.setStrokeWidth(.1f);
    clipPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    clipPaint.setXfermode(xFermode);

    textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setTextSize(96);//todo comfirm the textSize
    textPaint.setStrokeWidth(1f);
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    textPaint.setColor(valColor);



    bgPath = new Path();
    growthPath = new Path();

    //todo 暂定中心点为屏幕中心
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    w = metrics.widthPixels;
    h = metrics.heightPixels;

    outerRecF = new RectF(w / 2 - outerRadius, h / 2 - outerRadius, w / 2 + outerRadius, h / 2 + outerRadius);
    innerRecF = new RectF(w / 2 - innerRadius, h / 2 - innerRadius, w / 2 + innerRadius, h / 2 + innerRadius);

    rightBoundRecF = new RectF(w / 2 + (float) Math.pow(3, 0.5) * (innerRadius + gapRadius) / 2 - gapRadius,
            h / 2 + (innerRadius + gapRadius) / 2 - gapRadius,
            w / 2 + (float) Math.pow(3, 0.5) * (innerRadius + gapRadius) / 2 + gapRadius,
            h / 2 + (innerRadius + gapRadius) / 2 + gapRadius);

    leftBoundRecF = new RectF(w / 2 - (float) Math.pow(3, 0.5) * (innerRadius + gapRadius) / 2 - gapRadius,
            h / 2 + (innerRadius + gapRadius) / 2 - gapRadius,
            w / 2 - (float) Math.pow(3, 0.5) * (innerRadius + gapRadius) / 2 + gapRadius,
            h / 2 + (innerRadius + gapRadius) / 2 + gapRadius);

    bgClipPath = new Path();
    bgClipPath.arcTo(innerRecF, 150.0f, 359.9f, true);
    bgClipPath.close();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //bg
    float startAngle = 150.0f;
    float endRecfFullAngle = 180.0f;
    bgPath.arcTo(outerRecF, startAngle, bgFullAngle, true);
    bgPath.arcTo(rightBoundRecF, 30.0f, endRecfFullAngle, true);
    bgPath.arcTo(innerRecF, startAngle, bgFullAngle);
    bgPath.arcTo(leftBoundRecF, -30.0f, endRecfFullAngle);
    bgPath.rMoveTo(w / 2 - outerRadius * (float) Math.pow(3, 0.5) / 2, h / 2 + outerRadius / 2);
    bgPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.WINDING);
    bgPath.close();

    //growth
    if (getGrowthVal() != 0) {
        float temp = getGrowthAngle(getGrowthVal());
        growthPath.arcTo(outerRecF, startAngle, temp, true);
        growthPath.arcTo(getDynamicRecF(getGrowthVal()), getDynamicOriginAngle(getGrowthVal()), endRecfFullAngle, true);
        growthPath.arcTo(innerRecF, startAngle, temp);
        growthPath.arcTo(leftBoundRecF, -30.0f, endRecfFullAngle);
        growthPath.rMoveTo(w / 2 - outerRadius * (float) Math.pow(3, 0.5) / 2, h / 2 + outerRadius / 2);
        growthPath.close();
    }
    canvas.drawText(formatVal(getGrowthVal()), w / 2, h / 2, textPaint);
    canvas.clipPath(bgClipPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    canvas.drawPath(bgPath, bgPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(growthPath, growthPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(bgClipPath, clipPaint);
}

private float getDynamicOriginAngle(int growthVal) {
    return growthVal <= 30 ? getGrowthAngle(growthVal) + 150 :
            getGrowthAngle(growthVal) - 210;
}

private RectF getDynamicRecF(int growthVal) {
    float dynamicAngle = getGrowthAngle(growthVal);
    //动态圆心
    float _w = w / 2 + (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dynamicAngle - 120)) * (outerRadius - gapRadius);
    float _y = h / 2 - (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dynamicAngle - 30)) * (outerRadius - gapRadius);
    return new RectF(_w - gapRadius, _y - gapRadius, _w + gapRadius, _y + gapRadius);
}

private int getGrowthVal() {
    return this.growthValue;
}

public void setGrowthValue(int value) {
    if (value < 0 || value > 100000) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("成长值不在范围内");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.growthValue = value;
    invalidate();
}

private float getGrowthAngle(int growthVal) {
    return gapAngle * (getLevel(growthVal) - 1)
            + gapAngle * (growthVal - scores[getLevel(growthVal) - 1]) /
            (scores[getLevel(growthVal)] - scores[getLevel(growthVal) - 1]);
}

private int getLevel(int score) {
    return score < 0 ? -1 : score <= 10 ? 1 : score <= 80 ? 2 : score <= 180 ? 3 : score <= 800 ?
            4 : score <= 5000 ? 5 : score <= 20000 ? 6 : score <= 50000 ? 7 : 8;
}

private String formatVal(int value) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(value));
    return value < 1000 ? builder.toString() : builder.insert(builder.length() - 3, ',').toString();
}
```

}

Use the Xfermode Api with canvas.clipPath() may resolve this problem...
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfYVv.png)