# draw circle Drawable in canvas

Tags: android, canvas

i have an canvas with `width 400` and `height 100` i just draw on it some thing

and now i want to draw a Drawable

i draw it like this

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    iconDrawable.draw(canvas);
    // ... draw other thing

}
```

now the result its would be

[image]

what i want its only make the Drawable `Rounded` i seen some class like `RoundedImageView` and other but i didn't find good idea for convert my Drawable to circle and draw it in canvas not on all canvas small part on it

final result must be like

[image]

please  read question carefully before make it duplicate i want rounded drawable on part of canvas not on all canvas as i mentioned i read some class code like RoundedImageView ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw circle by canvas in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954596/how-to-draw-circle-by-canvas-in-android)

Comment: @DimaKozhevin thats draw `Drawable` or `Bitmap` on all canvas my question its draw on small part on left

Comment: @DimaKozhevin read question carefully please before make it duplicate

Comment: What prevents to establish the necessary radius and 'x' and 'y' for
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint); ?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin and where is the drawable ?

Comment: Well. Could you post your code where you draw your iconDrawable?

Comment: `iconDrawable.draw(canvas);` its in question 

`iconDrawable` an Drawable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RoundedBitmapDrawable` of `android.support.v4`.

```
Bitmap bm = ...;
RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bm);
drawable.setCornerRadius(Math.min(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight()));
drawable.setAntiAlias(true);
....
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

If you need to scale a drawable (set it's size), you should use

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
```

If you need to draw a drawable at (x,y) you should translate the canvas:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(x, y);
drawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

You can use `canvas.cliPath()` to clip drawable to any path:

```
    Rect b = drwable.getBounds();

    canvas.save();
    Path path = new Path();
    int w = b.right;
    int h = b.bottom;
    path.addCircle(w/2, h/2, w/2, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

if you need antialiasing, you can try theese questions:

[Antialias on clipPath on layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748652/antialias-on-clippath-on-layout)

[How do I antialias the clip boundary on Android's canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719535/how-do-i-antialias-the-clip-boundary-on-androids-canvas)

Comment: but i have drawable not bitmap :/

Comment: what kind of drawable do you have? the easiest way is to draw that drawable into bitmap. But if you specify a drawable type you use, may be I'll be able to show, how to draw that drawable in circle.

Comment: my drawable  its class extend `drawable`

Comment: i tried on drawable class
`canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,getBounds().width(), getBounds().height()), g, g,  paintx);` but the old draw (IMAGES)  its shown outside the circle

Comment: Added fix. Just use `canvas.clipPath()` to clip drawable to any path. Circular, for example.

Comment: clipPath and antialias :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719535/how-do-i-antialias-the-clip-boundary-on-androids-canvas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748652/antialias-on-clippath-on-layout